# Soft bodies go through each other

Tags: collections, soft-body

Help I'm trying to make soft bodies collide with each other but nothing seems to be working instead they just go through each other.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Answer (score 1):

Enable „collision“ for the soft bodies.

Your second picture in your question shows it. You will find it under the physics tab.